# Solution to website responds differently on IOS Chrome Browser than android chrome browser

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-chrome

Their is an website [Shikhar](https://shikhar.hulcd.com/tutorial) tries to open in  Windows browser, shows it can only accessed through Android App:[image: Screenshot for Reference]

But same website gets loaded on  chrome or any other browser on IOS devices or MAC device.
Need help to access this website on windows browsers or on android device browsers.